# Set up SSH tunnel on existing connection from script

Tags: ssh, python, ssh-tunneling

I want to establish an SSH tunnel on an existing connection. The tricky part is doing it from a script (a custom shell I need to allow users only some specific things, like setting up this tunnel).

Normally you can do:

```
<enter>
~C
ssh> -L 8080:localhost:80
```

But I need to be able to do this from a running python script. I tried:

```
print("\n~C -L 8080:localhost:80")
```

but that unfortunately was too simple a thought.

So, how do I setup the tunnel from a running Python script?

(as a side-issue, I also have to prevent `ssh -N -L x:host:y host.example.com`, but still allow port forwards to be set up with my custom shell).

Comment: I don't get it: were you planning to run that script on the client or on the server?

Comment: On the server, as a shell where people log in. However, I think I have a working solution now: I just setup the tunnel with `nc -l 2222 0<backpipe | nc host.example.com 22 1>backpipe`

Comment: the client specifies a tunnel to set up; the server allows it or not.

Comment: I actually ran into more problems. I solved it by writing a proxy tool myself in C++/Qt.

Answer (score 2):

Try use [`sshtunnel`](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel) lib.

Example:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from time import sleep

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('localhost', 2222),
    ssh_username="vagrant",
    ssh_password="vagrant",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as server:

    print(server.local_bind_port)
    while True:
        # press Ctrl-C for stopping
        sleep(1)

print('FINISH!')
```

or CLI:

```
python -m sshtunnel -U vagrant -P vagrant -L :3306 -R 127.0.0.1:3306 -p 2222 localhost
```

Comment: I'll keep it in mind for the future. For now, I solved it by writing a proxy in C++/Qt myself.